# CSS isn't loading to style HTML-connected to static in Django

Tags: html, css, django

So basically I can't manage to connect .css file to my .html.
Previously it just wasn't finding the .css file but after I've referenced the full path it stopped giving me the 'not found' error on cmd local host so it does find it it just doesn't apply it to change styling.
The .html and .css files are in the same folder, I already tried putting the css in both /static and /media folders, neither worked

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=C:\Users\Any1\Desktop\personal_portfolio- 
 project\blog\templates\blog\master.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example heading</h1>
    <p>Lori is home blog</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

#just trying to change h1 color to red for testing

```
    h1 { color: #FF0000;

}
```

#and my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: please edit your post- replace the images with code snippets containing the parts of the code that are relevant for your question.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=C:\Users\Any1\Desktop\personal_portfolio-
```

write it like this

```html
    {% load static %}
    .
    .
    .
    {% block css %}

    <link href="{% static 'css/master.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    {% endblock %}
```

make sure your css is at '/static/css/master.css'

Comment: Thanks  a lot Mark! It also works with just                                                                              
                                                                 {% load static %}                                                <link href="{% static 'css/master.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0):

@Mark Rofail

thanks so much that fixed it.
I just did

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'css/master.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```